# Is it possible to integrate data visualizations rendered in Blender into Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visualization, blender

I would like to create some more sophisticated data visualizations. Ideally those visualizations would be interactive. Now I have already some experience using Blender and I am wondering if it possible to integrate animations into Jupyter Notebooks. I am thinking about a combination of something like [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-next-level-of-data-visualization-in-python-dd6e99039d5e) (plotly, etc.) and [this](https://medium.com/@contra/using-blender-to-run-python-and-visualizing-fourier-series-a282663b972c) (Blender Scripting).

For example, it would be nice to render an interactive map displaying data for various geographical reagions. Has anyone tried this and some recommendations ?